# returning data in python

Tags: python, return-type

I'm currently looking through the "Dive Into Python" to pick up the language and I was a bit confused about chapter 5's example 5.10. UserDict Normal Methods

Example 5.10. UserDict Normal Methods

```
def copy(self):
    if self.__class__ is UserDict:
        return UserDict(self.data)
    import copy
    return copy.copy(self)
```

where `data` is a dictionary.

I notice that if the class is a UserDict type, then it returns `UserDict(self.data)`. What I'm confused about is, why do you need to return `UserDict(self.data)` instead of just returning `self.data`? Isn't self.data a dictionary which you can return?

If someone can explain the difference between returning `UserDict(self.data)` and `self.data`, I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Thank you everyone, for all your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to yield a copy, you should use `UserDict(self.data)`.

Why we use `UserDict(self.data)` instead of self.data is that it returns new instance which is same class with self.

If you return only `self.data` then you didn't make a copy. Because it returns a `dict`, not an instance of `UserDict`. If you want to produce a copy, you should use `UserDict(self.data)`.

Answer (score 2):

It returns a new `UserDict` object because `.copy()` is expected to return an object of the same type its copying.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking at here is an optimization.

You can use `UserDict` as a base class to write your own subclass. If you don't override the `copy()` method on your subclass, then you get the one from the base class, i.e., the one you're looking at here.

So basically, it's checking to see if it's running in a subclass. If it's not, it knows that the fastest way to make a copy of itself is to use its own constructor. But if it's running in a subclass, it doesn't know what you might have added and what needs to be copied, so it uses a more generic copy function from the `copy` module. This won't be as fast, but it is more likely to copy what needs to be copied. (Of course, you should maybe write your own `copy()` method if you subclass `UserDict`...)

It doesn't return `self.data` because `self.data` is a `dict`, not a `UserDict`, and it's not a copy.